# how to load Angualr.js controller based on condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm creating a pretty big and complex application. it's have more then 100+ controllers and bunch of third party libraries , like jquery , lodash , angualr material etc. and i'm including all those in single index.html file. even im using Css & Javascript minifier to compress all my file, but it's getting bigger in size each time i'm adding new feature to my site.
so if the user visit to my sites it will take long time to download all the files and it will take lot of time to render my page completely. even though my index page need 10% of all files. it's really horrible.
So is there any better solution to load my controllers based on condition dynamically. so i don't have to include all the controllers in my index.html file. 
Thanks for your time

Comment: Split your project into smaller parts. Create folders, each with its own controller, etc

Comment: i did the same thing. i created my folder by features and then by types. but the problem is here for eg-  i created authController.js in my auth directory . but we still have to include it on my index.html. this is the problem ? i don't want to include my AuthController.js to my index.html instead i wants to kinda load it on index.html when my auth view and services loaded to view.  any comments on that .. thanks ??

Answer (score 0):

take a look at RequireJS: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/
and https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs